# Why are multiple objects created in below implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is a very simple code where I was trying to implement a very basic ordered in-app cache. I was expecting that, in each call on `services.cache`, I will get the same `id` throughout app lifetime. But the value differs. What is the reason behind this?

What I understand is that, `self.__cache` should reuse the first `InAppCache` object it creates. What I am missing here?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys


class InAppCache(OrderedDict):
    MAX_MEMORY = 50 * 10 ** 6

    def add(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def remove(self, key):
        return self.popitem(last=False)

    def is_remove_needed(self):
        return sys.getsizeof(self) > self.MAX_MEMORY

    def reset(self):
        self.clear()


class Services:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__cache = None

    @property
    def cache(self):
        if not self.__cache:
            self.__cache = InAppCache()
        print(id(self.__cache))
        return self.__cache


services = Services()
services.cache
services.cache
services.cache
services.cache
services.cache
services.cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `OrderedDict`, which is a subclass of `dict`, is considered *falsey* if empty. So your `if not self.__cache` test is always true until you put something into the dict. Use `if self.__cache is None` instead.

Comment: Beside, what's the point of initializing to `None`? I mean that object is not a heavy object that requires reading files etc so lazy initialization doesn't seem to be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `bool(ordered_dict)` is `False`. Use `self.__cache is None` instead.